# Index does not remain consistent after deleting an item

Tags: android

I am using AbsListView.MultiChoiceModeListener for selecting multiple items in my project.
The problem is , when i select multiple items and delete in between one, the selected items below that deleted one gets disturbed.

e.g My list is having items as follows and i have selected A D and E:

**A** 
B
C
**D** 
**E**

If i delete B in between, my new list becomes like this.And A C and D gets selected
**A** 
B
**C**
**D** 
E

Using adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() method, but its not working

Answer (score 0):

detect the deleted index and shift your selected items manually

im not really at work right now, but you should be able to detect the index of the deleted item , in your example it is 1. now on delete, recheck the index of your selection. for each item where the index is larger than 1, subtract the value.

Comment: But it will increase the manual work right. I was assuming we can do it in some another way. Thanks